# C# Core 3.1 - Getting error message "The SSL connection could not be established" when calling HttpClient SendAsync()

Tags: c#, ssl, httpclient, tls1.2, asp.net-core-3.1

Env: Console App, C# Core 3.1, VS 2019

I'm executing the following line:

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
{"The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233087
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: {"Authentication failed, see inner exception."}
    Message: "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."
    Source: "System.Net.Http"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.<EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at ...
```

Did some googling and found this:

```
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28189
```

So I added

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```

right before the above line.  Still getting the error.

I have a bunch of code prior to the executed line:

```
httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12
};
```

Plus code to add the certificate, header, content-type, etc.  Not sure what is actually causing the error.  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Added the following:```httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender,certificate,chain,sslPolicyError)=>{return true;}; ```. This gives me a new error: ```System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 --->System.Net.Http.WinHttpException(80072F8F,12175):Error12175 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'A security error occurred'.
at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.StartRequestAsync(WinHttpRequestState state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---```

Comment: i got this same error in dotnet core 2.2

Comment: I ended up using the RestSharp library.

Comment: Can you share your solution? I also tried to switch to RestSharp because of that error buit I keep getting it with RestSharp

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember what I did to resolve this.

Comment: @MyDisplayName do you happen to recall now what you did to resolve this?